# Opening a command prompt in another location - XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, context-menu

In Windows 7, shift-right-clicking on a Explorer window brings up `'Open Command Window Here'`, which I cannot find in Windows XP. I heard you have to edit the registry, so I tried using [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/232/right-click-to-open-a-command-prompt/) source. However, it is not showing up in the context menu as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I figured it out. If you want to get cmd to open in another location in XP, use `cd` and then the path. e.g. if it's `C:\Documents and Settings\user> _` and it is waiting for you to write something, then you can type `cd (name of directory)`. For example, `cd C:\new folder`.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I add "Open Command Window Here" to Windows XP?

Use the [Open Command Window Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/xp-downloads#2TC=powertoys) PowerToy.

There are other solutions (which require modifying the registry) at [Add the Command Prompt to the Windows Explorer Right-Click Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu/).

---

#### Open Command Window Here

> Easy access: Open command windows (cmd.exe) quickly with this file system folder shortcut. [Download Link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=211471)

Source [Windows XP downloads - PowerToys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/xp-downloads#2TC=powertoys)

Comment: I tried the toy and modifying the registry. It still does not show up.

Comment: @Player72 The instructions at [Add the Command Prompt to the Windows Explorer Right-Click Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu/) are **different** to the ones in the link in your question ...

Comment: Done, although no result. Do you have to 'save' the registry or does it do that by itself?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anthing extra to *save* the changes. I don't know why they don't work for you :/

Comment: I figured it out. Instead you could just type `cd` and then the path and it will also work. Thanks for your help!